# Rails localized numericality validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The numericality validation in Rails checks with the english '.' seperator and ',' delimiter by default. I enabled the german locale in my app, but the validation doesn't seem to take notice automatically - do I have to write my own validation or is there a better "Rails-way" of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The standard validator does not care about I18n format.

And probably you should not change the format for numeric fields.

What I do for this is generally to create a virtual field doing the translation of format and creating a custom validator (code below from memory and probably not the best)

```
def amount_f
  I18n.l amount
end

def amount_f=(val)
  amount = val ? val.gsub(',','.') : nil
end
```